# Accessing Express.js req or session from static html page

Tags: html, node.js, express

How to access Express.js req or session from static html page, for example, how to show the log-in username on the top of the index.html page

Comment: The question is unclear, please explain yourself more clearly

Comment: hmmm... i am not sure why it's not clear, it's simple, i just need to know how to inject the session variables inside the static html pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need template engine.

For example:

If you use [swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/):

index.html:

```
<span>{{name}}</span>
```

index.js:

```
res.render("index.html",{
    name:req.session.userName
});
```

Express support many [template engines](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/),you can [choose one](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) as you like.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's what i was looking for. i tried to accept your answer but it required 15 points to do that, any idea how to pass that? thanks again

Answer (score 4):

you have to use a template engine.
JADE comes by default with express and for html you can use ejs.
It works like similar to JSP like <% %>

eg:-if you have passed something like this:

```
router.get('/userDash',function(req,res){
..... 

 res.render('userDash',{user:req.session.username});

});
```

Now you can use the variable user passed by <%= user %> in html like:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Welcome <%= user %> </h1> 
</body>
</html>             


                             or
```

create an api which returns the current user logged in or return null if no user logged in like:

```
router.get('/user',function(req,res){
  if(req.session && req.session.username){
    res.send(req.session.username);
  }
  else{
    res.send('noUser');
  }
}
```

make an ajax call to it in html whenever required and you will get the info about the current user logged in.(well this is not a good way of doing it,well it worked for me in session handling at html side)